# Telerik Reports

Tags: c#, telerik

Am trying to access telerik reports from a c# class. Am using the Telerik.Reporting.Report() method but haven't succeeded. Please if you can help me find a way to access these reports from c# classes i'll appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to access them? Why haven't you succeeded? Can you show your code, and the exception you are receiving, or at least a description of the behaviour you are encountering?

Comment: var typeReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.Report(); am using this but dont know what to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create an object of the report in your class.

```
Report1 rpt = new Report1();
```

Next, create a new object of the `Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor`.

```
ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor()
```

In my case, I want to email my report as a PDF. Therefore I do the following.

```
RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", rpt, null);
email(result.DocumentBytes)
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks gotten somewhere. I need some more help please. How do i pass parameters?

Comment: Have actually figured it out. Thanks.